# can't run default/hello-minikube application in browser

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am new to devops stuff and just started learning Kubernetes. I installed minikube and kubernetes-cli with homebrew and then setup docker drivers

```
minikube start --driver=docker
minikube config set driver docker
```

I created hello-minikube sample application

```
$kubectl create deployment hello-minikube --image=k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4
$ kubectl expose deployment hello-minikube --type=NodePort --port=8080
Error from server (AlreadyExists): services "hello-minikube" already exists
```

and then tried to start it

```
❯ minikube service hello-minikube
|-----------|----------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |      NAME      | TARGET PORT |            URL            |
|-----------|----------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| default   | hello-minikube |        8080 | http://192.168.49.2:31510 |
|-----------|----------------|-------------|---------------------------|
  Starting tunnel for service hello-minikube.
|-----------|----------------|-------------|------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |      NAME      | TARGET PORT |          URL           |
|-----------|----------------|-------------|------------------------|
| default   | hello-minikube |             | http://127.0.0.1:52658 |
|-----------|----------------|-------------|------------------------|
  Opening service default/hello-minikube in default browser...
❗  Because you are using a Docker driver on darwin, the terminal needs to be open to run it.
```

But in browser it just see **The connection was reset** error so it doesn't load the application. What do you think went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

On inspection

```
$ kubectl describe pod hello-minikube

$ kubectl get nodes
```

I found that I was running x86 container on ARM Macbook M1. Installed on x86 Linux and everything works as expected

https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/13129